# Conditional Probability with Cumulative Sum

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, dice

Suppose you roll a fair 6-sided die and accumulate the sum until you've reached a sum $>= 1000$. What is the probability your final roll is a $6$?

> your final roll must be on an integer in $[994, 999]$. From $999$ all rolls sum to at least $1000$ so there are $6$ outcomes, $994$ has just one outcome. Total number of outcomes is $6+5+4+3+2+1$ $6$ of which involve rolling a $6$ thus probability is $\frac6{21}$ Is this a valid solution?

Comment: As a rough estimate, sure, but it can not be equal to exactly this.  To see that, we can use elementary number theory, noting that if we wanted to we could keep rolling until we rolled exactly 1000 times total and just ignore the excess rolls when determining what the "final" roll is.  This implies that our probability will be of the form $\frac{N}{6^{1000}}$ for some $N$ and if we write this in simplified form will be of the form $\frac{n}{2^a3^b}$ for some integers $n,a,b$ with $\gcd(n,2)=\gcd(n,3)=1$.  You can not have it in simplified form have a factor of $7$ in the denominator.

Comment: The punchline is that after so many dice throws, you will at least be *near* equal probability that the respective numbers are reached, but truly becoming equal happens at the limit and not after finite amounts of time.  Otherwise, your approach is correct and verifiable through simulation.  Getting the *exact* probability however would be incredibly tedious and would be infeasible even with computer assistance.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, so are you saying as we increase the sum to $>= n$ as $n$ approaches infinity, the probability will approach $\frac27$?

Comment: The probability you ask about that our final roll upon reaching a specified threshold is a six will approach $\frac{6}{21}$.  The probability that, say... we eventually hit a sum of exactly a billion, will approach $\frac{2}{7}$.

Comment: I was apparently still half asleep.  I realize now that $\frac{6}{21}=\frac{2}{7}$...  yes either way.